# Can I run cron with a simple command without having to declare it in a script?

Tags: command-line, php, cron

I'm running a server with Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx, and PHP-5. Would cron work, if I issue the command like this :

```
10 * * * * service php5-fpm restart
```

Or do I need to put this command in a script and call it from here? Basically, I'm just using cron to restart `php5-fpm` every 10 minutes.

Comment: Use the full path to the command

Comment: This won't run _every_ 10 minutes but every hour _at_ minute 10 (12:10, 13:10, 14:10, etc.).

Comment: */10 * * * * ... will run every 10 minutes.

Comment: @Unbesiegbarkeit please use code formatting for commands, configuration, etc., not quote formatting. See http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code and https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11763/158442

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter whether `crontab` (edited by invoking `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`, if you need a command to be called with higher privileges) contains a script to be executed or a command. If you would like to put a command directly into a `crontab` it should look like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart
```

You have to use the full path `/usr/sbin/service` because `/usr/sbin` is not in cron's default `PATH`.

`*/x` means a command is executed once for every *x* of time (minutes, hours, etc.).